# Creating AWS Lambda function using python pyodbc library throw an error "module 'pyodbc' has no attribute ' connect'

Tags: python, sql-server, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I am trying to create a simple Lambda function to query the `msdb` of AWS RDS SQL server to monitor for failed jobs. I downloaded the python module pyodbc from https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/tree/master/lambda_packages/pyodbc
changed the file type from .tar.gz to zip and extracted the two file libodbc.so.2 and pyodbc.so I then put the two files in a zip folder structured like this
`pythonjob.zip\python\lib\python3.7\site-packages\pyodbc` and in `pyodbc` exists `libodbc.so.2` and `pyodbc.so`
I then uploaded the `pythonjob.zip` file on Lambda Layer and tested my script

```
import pyodbc
print(dir(pyodbc))

#ConnectionValues

endpoint = 'myservername.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
database_name = 'msdb'
conn = pyodbc.Connect( server= endpoint, user= username, password=password, database= database_name)
```

However I am getting the error  `[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'Connect'` and the print(dir(pyodbc)) prints `['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

I am not sure what to do now. Your help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use "connect" attribute instead of "Connect" (capital C)?

Comment: @Aditya that also shows the same error ```"errorMessage": "module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'connect'"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Esu Please change the connection statement to below:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+endpoint+';DATABASE='+database_name+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

Also, The lambda layer which you're using doesn't contain the required packages. You can download the file from the below link, upload zip to the lambda layer and try the connection again.

https://github.com/alexanderluiscampino/lambda-layers/blob/master/pyodbc-9ef8961d-ce5b-4603-b397-03c9a6316eca.zip

Hope it works.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file, uploaded it to layer and changed the connection as you suggest and Voila! it work. Thank you so much @Aditya

Answer (score 0):

The error here seems to be from `pyodbc.Connect`. you have `pyodbc.Connect` instead of `pyodbc.connect`. Your `C` is in capital letters rather than small letter `c`.

So this will work:

```
import pyodbc
print(dir(pyodbc))

#ConnectionValues

endpoint = 'myservername.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
database_name = 'msdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect( server= endpoint, user= username, password=password, database= database_name)
```